# "SystemError: E:Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Extra junk at end of file" causing package manager to break

Tags: package-management

I have a problem with ubuntu software center. When I try to launch it from the dock the icon blinks and then closes. If I try to launch it from terminal I get this message.

```
gksarkis@ubuntu:~$ gksudo software-center

(gksudo:2919): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksudo:2919): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksudo:2919): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksudo:2919): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 44, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.utils import ExecutionTime
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py", line 682, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.pkginfo import get_pkg_info
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from debfile import DebFileApplication
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 21, in <module>
    from apt import Cache
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    apt_pkg.init()
SystemError: E:Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Extra junk at end of file
sarkis@ubuntu:~$
```

Also when I try to install a software from terminal I get this message.

```
sarkis@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get cheese
[sudo] password for sarkis: 
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Extra junk at end of file
sarkis@ubuntu:~$
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance for your help.

*There is a red button at the top bar that displays:
An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what's wrong.
The error message was 'Unkown Error': '(E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Extra junk at end of file)'

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1453196/

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? And which desktop environment?

Comment: It looks like there's a mangled file, please post the file ` /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` on pastebin.ubuntu.com and then add the link to your question, thanks!

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 11.10

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1453196/

Comment: Are you sure that's right? It just shows an empty file there.

Comment: I'm sorry, here's the link http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1453256/

Comment: @SarkisKuri: Please include the output of `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf`

Answer (score -1):

Command line error:

```
sudo apt-get install <application> 

sudo apt-get remove <application>
```

I would suggest trying synaptic to reinstall the software center

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
I can't install synaptic.
I have ubuntu 11.10 :(

Comment: synaptic is in the default repos. use `sudo apt-get install synaptic` in the terminal to install

Comment: I tried to install synaptic as you said so and it gave me this message:

sarkis@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
[sudo] password for sarkis: 
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Extra junk at end of file
sarkis@ubuntu:~$